# The server container will not exit when the other two containers have exited

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

So I have three containers, for testing purpose: 1 dev-server 2 selenium-headless 3 unit.

They all run parallel and it works fine. The only problem is that my 1 dev-server container does not exit/stop when the other two have exited and done running the tests. I also want it to exit with code 1 if one of the other containers exit with code 1, of course.

What should I do and add for it to exit after the other two containers are exited?

My docker-compose file looks like this. :

```
version: "3"

services:
  dev-server:
    build: .
    tty: true
    hostname: yeti-ui
    container_name: yeti-ui
    ports: 
      - 127.0.0.01:8080:8080
      - 35729:35729
    environment:
      - "SKIP_DOCS=0"
      - "SCHEME=http"
      - "NODE_ENV=stage"
    entrypoint: npm
    command: run dev-server

  headless-chrome:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-headless-chrome
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    network_mode: "host"

  unit-test:
    build: .
    entrypoint: npm
    command: test
```

I cant use `--abort-on-container-exit` or `--exit-on-code` because I need the other two to be done before the dev-server stops.

This is how I run in makefile:

```
docker-selenium-headless
    docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm -f
    docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Not sure, but is `tty: true` needed in "dev-server"?

Comment: Your   headless-chrome is serving unit-test. So when unit-test finishes the headless can exit and then the dev-server. Why is `--abort-on-container-exit or --exit-on-code` not ok for you?